# Snowflake SQL code to show only second record for items with duplicate ID

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to get my head around SQL and am using Snowflake as a testbed to do this. I have a table with products which have multiple reviews against them. I am trying to structure a query to only show products with 2 or more reviews and then only show the second review. As I say, this is merely me trying to better understand SQL so selecting the second review is a random ask. The table is made up of 4 columns. 1 is Product ID, 2 is Product Name, 3 is Review and 4 is Date Review was posted.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Hi Gordon, see above for an example table and what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `row_number()` for this type of query:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id order by date_review asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 2;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for the suggestion. Apologies for my basic understanding, but what does t refer to? Thanks.

Comment: @Marc . . . It is the name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowing function like `ROW_NUMBER()` to make numbered groupings, eg:

```
WITH Review_Sequence (
  SELECT r.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_ID ORDER BY Review_Date) Review_No
  FROM Reviews r
)
SELECT * FROM Review_Sequence WHERE Review_No = 2
```

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you replying. Apologies for my lack of understanding but what does r refer to? Thanks.

Comment: It's a table alias: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: r is a table alias for the Reviews table.  I use it only because I'm lazy and it allows me to use SELECT r.* to get all the columns of Reviews.  When I add a column I can't use SELECT * anymore.